# Send bash environment variable back to python fabric

Tags: python, bash, fabric

I am attempting to pass a bash environment variable back into my fabric function like this:-

```
from fabric.api import env

def env_localhost():
    "All the environment variables relating to your localhost"
    project_home = local('echo $PROJECT_HOME')
    print 111, project_home
```

But it doesn't seem to be able to retrieve the stdout results and assign it to my python `project_home` variable. What's the correct way to do this right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
import os
os.getenv("PATH")
```

Comment: ah, good point. should have thought of it instead of digging into the fabric rabbit hole. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
import os
os.environ['PROJECT_HOME']
```