# Using environment variables in Fabric

Tags: python, bash, fabric, cd

Assuming:

```
export TEST=/somewhere
```

I want to run the command `/somewhere/program` using:

```
with cd('$TEST'):
  run('program')
```

However, this doesn't work because the `$` gets escaped.

Is there a way to use an environment variable in a Fabric `cd()` call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following suggestion from @AndrewWalker, here is a more compact solution that worked for me (and to my knowledge, the result is the same):

```
with cd(run("echo $TEST")):
  run("program")
```

But I decided to go for a (very slightly) more concise yet as readable solution:

```
run('cd $TEST && program')
```

This second solution, if I am correct, produces the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the value by using echo

```
testdir = str(run("echo $TEST"))
with cd(testdir):
    run("program")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I used it to write my own (given below). Please correct me if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
import os

def my_task():
    with lcd(os.environ['TEST_PATH']):
        local('pwd')
```

`os.getenv('TEST_PATH')` may also be used (with a default, optionally)

Hat tip: [Send bash environment variable back to python fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203210/send-bash-environment-variable-back-to-python-fabric?rq=1)

Comment: Note that this will only work for local environment variables (which is what I needed, thanks!)